# Can we list inbuilt Singleton class with proper explanation why these classes require Singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

I want to make list of inbuilt singleton classes available in Java and reason for making them singleton.

For E.G.

```
java.lang.Runtime
```

Reason: since on whole Java application only one runtime environment can be possible.

```
java.awt.Toolkit
```

Reason: AWT needs only a single object to perform the binding and the object is relatively expensive to create

Can we list out all singleton classes in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Well the Java Docs spring to mind. E.G. for [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html):

> Every Java application has a **single instance** of class `Runtime` that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running. The current runtime can be obtained from the `getRuntime` method.
>
> *An application cannot create its own instance of this class.*

---

> Can we list out all singleton classes in Java?

Possibly by parsing the HTML of the Java Docs and looking for 'single' or 'singleton'.  Though I cannot imagine that would be very robust.  AFAIU there is no simple marker for them.

Comment: *"..but i need to list out in stackoverflow"*  What do you mean by that?  *"..so we need not to refer any other site.."*  Then you are doomed.  I've coded Java for over 10 years.  The Java Docs are **permanently open** as the 2nd tab in my browser, and I refer to them 'every other hour'.  There is no way I could imagine being an effective programmer without them.

Comment: yes you are right but i don't found any doc or site that gives for such list and i am learning singleton so i found many classes are there in java itself are singleton so i want to make list just for knowledge 
if any thing wrong then i can remove my post

Comment: *" if any thing wrong"*  No it is fine.  I am not sure what I wrote to make you think otherwise.  It is just a subject about which I speak with passion, from a wealth of experience. *"..then i can remove my post"* Please don't do that.

Comment: I think this question may not fulfill requirement of this forum that's why i say that  "if any thing wrong then i can remove my post"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Note that if other people think it is off-topic, they can (if they have enough rep.) vote to close.  I would be *very* surprised if that happened, since I can cannot think of any valid close reason that applies to this question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are allot of Singleton classes in Java.,  following are few predefined Singleton classes in core Java

```
1. java.lang.Runtime 
2. java.awt.Toolkit
3. java.sql.DriverManager, even implementation of java.sql.Connection interface is Singleton.
```

There are many more.

Side Note  ⇒ Please go though the Java docs online and look for public classes with no public constructors and a parameterless method that returns an instance of it's class. Usually that'll be one.